# xgboost.train probability output needed

Tags: xgboost, predict

XGBClassifier outputs probabilities if we use the method "predict_proba", however, when I train the model using xgboost.train, I cannot figure out how to get probabilities as output. Here is a chunk of my code:

```
dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y)
param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}
modelXG=xgb.train(param,dtrain,xgb_model='xgbmodel')
```

Comment: Run the `predict_proba` method with the training dataset?

Comment: The problem with that is: xgboost.train does not have the predict_proba method.

Answer (score 8):

`xgboost.train()` returns a `xgb.Booster` object. The `xgb.Booster.predict()` call returns **probabilities** in the case of a classification problem instead of the expected labels, if you are used to the `.predict()`methods of sklearn models. So `modelXG.predict(dtest)` call will give you want you need.

Comment: `the xgb.Booster.predict() call returns probabilities in the case of a classification problem instead of the expected labels`

This is non-obvious in the XGBoost documentation or am I blind?

Comment: Yes, it is not apparent. I learned it by looking into the predicting methods of the sklearn API. @ZdWhite If you feel strong about it- I'm sure developers will be happy to get a PR with an improvement to the docs

Comment: And does xgboost.Booster.predict() return probabilities of being...class 0 or class 1? Just making sure.